# How to pass an "enter" to the external application?

Tags: external-calls

I have been trying to make an `.exe` file that I have become more automated by using *Mathematica*, but I am having trouble getting it to work. The file is based in command prompt and I basically need to do:

1. Open program
2. enter string
3. press enter key
4. enter string
5. press enter key
6. enter string
7. press enter key
8. press enter key

I do not need any of the output from the program since it is making a new txt file for me which I will read separately. I do not know how to go about "pressing the enter key" or even inputting the string I need to. I can get *Mathematica* to open the file with `SystemOpen[]`, but I can not get it to enter anything through *Mathematica* itself. Let me know if you need anymore clarification!

Comment: Please check if the you are happy with the new title. I changed it in hope that then more people with a similar question will find this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the manual for [`StartProcess`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StartProcess.html). With a small adaptation to the example given there you should be able to achieve the goal.

Just an example application

```
pathtoexe = "echo";
```

Opens a *stream*, which in Mathematica is called `ProcessObject`

```
process = StartProcess[pathtoexe]
```

Writes three lines to a *standard input*:

```
WriteLine[process, "write string one"];
WriteLine[process, "write string two"];
WriteLine[process, "write string three"];
```

Note, that each time `WriteLine` by default already adds the "enter" as a hidden linefeed character `\n`. Thus, if you just need an extra "enter" in the end, just send a empty string once more:

```
WriteLine[process, ""];
```

Close the process, if it already has not stopped:

```
KillProcess[process]
```

If this does not solve your problem, then please extend your question with a more specific example, such that we could run the same code as you and help you more efficiently.

Comment: This ended up working! Thank you very much for the fast help!!!

Comment: You are welcome! Do not forget to accept and upvote the solution, which you find helpful!